# Looping through Views doesn't generate right result

Tags: java, android

I am trying to add a bunch of views to my LinearLayout.

```
for (Business b : businesses) {
  View view = getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.card_item, mLinearLayout, true);

  ImageView mImageView = (ImageView) view.findViewById(R.id.image);

  Picasso.with(getBaseContext())
            .load(b.getPhotoUrl())
            .into(mImageView);

  TextView mTextView = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.title);
  mTextView.setText(b.getName());
}
```

However, it displays 1 card with info. Then 19 blank views.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
   for (Business b : businesses) {
   View view = getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.card_item, mLinearLayout, false);

   ImageView mImageView = (ImageView) view.findViewById(R.id.image);

  Picasso.with(getBaseContext())
        .load(b.getPhotoUrl())
        .into(mImageView);

 TextView mTextView = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.title);
 mTextView.setText(b.getName());

 mLinearLayout.addView(view);
 }
```